# Redirect the user to route in a view helper

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2

In my View Helper, I need to redirect the user to route. Do you know how I can do that ?

My View helper :

```
namespace MyProject\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Zend\Session\Container;
use Zend\Http\Response;


class Connected extends AbstractHelper
{

  public function __invoke()
  {

    $Session = new Container('base');
    $Response = new Response;

    if(!$Session->offsetExists('user_id'))
      return $Response->toRoute('auth');
  }

}
```

The php error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Zend\\Http\\Response::toRoute() in /SRV/www/firewall/ZendFramework/module/MyProject/src/MyProject/View/Helper/Connected.php on line 19
```

Thanks you for you help all !
Best regards,

Comment: Please see the answer provided in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468200/zf2-use-redirect-in-outside-of-controller

Comment: Dimi you may post this as an answer to your own question for other users to get more references :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, but I have solved my problem.

I know is not the better solution but that work fine:

```
class Connected extends AbstractHelper
{

  private $global;

  public function __construct($global)
  {
    $this->global = $global;
  }

  public function __invoke()
  {
    # Call the container
    $Session = new Container('base');

    # If the session doesn't exist, we redirect the user
    if(!$Session->offsetExists('user_id'))
      header('Location: ' . $this->global['global']['url']);

  }

}
```

Thanks you all for your help !